# Problem with Observer Pattern and generics in Java

Tags: java, generics, observer-pattern

I have made a generic Observer interface and an Observable class, but can't compile my class due to some generics problem. I don't know precisely why what I'm trying to do is forbidden. The code follows:

```
public class Observable<U> {

    private List<Observer<Observable<U>, U>> _observers = 
            new ArrayList<Observer<Observable<U>, U>>();

    public void addObserver(Observer<? extends Observable<U>, U> obs) {
        if (obs == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        if (_observers.contains(obs)) {
           return;
        }
        _observers.add(obs); // This line does not compile
    }

    public void notifyObservers(U data) {
        for (Observer<? extends Observable<U>, U> obs : _observers) {
            // After correction of the list declaration, this line will not compile
            obs.update(this, data); 
        }        
    }
}

interface Observer<T, U> {
    public void update(T entity, U arg);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the specific error message(s) you are getting?

Comment: After correcting the list declaration: From Eclipse: The method atualizar(capture#4-of ? extends Observable<U>, U) in the type Observer<capture#4-of ? extends Observable<U>,U> is not applicable for the arguments (Observable<U>, U)

Comment: Replace "atualizar" for "update" in my previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 public class Observable<U> {

        private List<Observer<Observable<U>, U>> _observers =
                new ArrayList<Observer<Observable<U>, U>>();

        public void addObserver(Observer<Observable<U>, U> obs) {
            if (obs == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            if (_observers.contains(obs)) {
               return;
            }
            _observers.add(obs);            }

        public void notifyObservers(U data) {
            for (Observer<? super Observable<U>, U> obs : _observers) {
                obs.atualizar(this, data);
            }
        }
    }

    interface Observer<T, U> {
        public void atualizar(T entity, U arg);
    }
```

To explain the underlying problem here, generics are forcing an explicit downcast. So you can't take any 'Observable' for any implementation of U and put it into a collection, because that collection is defined as taking a specific type of U, not anything.

For this type of use case, generics have limits, and you may not be able to accomplish what you want in such a type safe way.

EDIT: Would this work for you?

```
public class Observable<U> {

       private List<Observer<U>> _observers =
               new ArrayList<Observer<U>>();

       public void addObserver(Observer<U> obs) {
           if (obs == null) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException();
           }
           if (_observers.contains(obs)) {
              return;
           }
           _observers.add(obs);            }

       public void notifyObservers(U data) {
           for (Observer<U> obs : _observers) {
               obs.atualizar(this, data);
           }
       }
   }

   interface Observer<U> {
       public void atualizar(Observable<U> entity, U arg);
   }
```

Comment: This solves the problem at method notifyObservers(), but the problem ate method addObserver() remains.

Comment: Error message: The method add(Observer<Observable<U>,U>) in the type List<Observer<Observable<U>,U>> is not applicable for the arguments (Observer<capture#3-of ? extends Observable<U>,U>)

Comment: In what I posted there is no more extends. Did you change the other method signature as well?

Comment: I tried again your code and it does compile. Unfortunately, I extended Observable and I need to "observe" such subclasses, so the signature of addObserver() needs to accept and Observer that can watch over subclasses of Observable.

Comment: But it is it always for the same type of U?

Comment: I created a class "Request extends Observable<RequestEvent>" and a class "RequestEvent". I need then to create an "Observer<Request, RequestEvent>". Well, I wanted that the class Observer had no knowledge of the Observable class, but if this is not possible, then I guess it's a reasonable solution. I just need to be able to use observers that watch subclasses of Observable.

Comment: What do you do in the update method if you don't know the superclass of either object? I would say knowing about the Observable is unavoidable, but you could make it an interface to loosen the coupling further.

Answer (score 6):

Change your _observers definition to this:

```
private List<Observer<? extends Observable<U>, U>> _observers = 
        new ArrayList<Observer<? extends Observable<U>, U>>();
```

If you want to allow sublclasses you need to specify this in the declaration, not just in the place you're using it

Comment: That solves the problem, but is there a reason I should specify that in the declaraton also?

That correction caused another problem in other part of the code. I will edit the question and post everything.